# Char to int. Haskell

Tags: haskell

I wonder if there is any function I described below is available in `Prelude`. Is it?
(I know about `ord`, but it is in `Data.Char`)

I am looking for:

```
f :: Char -> Int
f 'a' = 0
f 'b' = 1
....
```

Comment: I am not sure I follow. Do you want any function with that type signature in Prelude since `ord` does not return those values for `a`, `b`, etc.

Comment: Why there should be any duplicate functionality in Haskell libraries?

Comment: Why not just import Data.Char?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
f x = fromEnum x - fromEnum 'a'
```

Comment: I didn't know about `fromEnum`. Thanks ;)